Folder suddenly empty / files missing
I have used Kubuntu for a few months now but I have a problem with files disappearing. I have an internal SSD, where I save most of my files, since it is larger than the main drive.
When switching to Ubuntu from Windows I noticed that some files where missing but I thought that might have been due to user error.
Now it seems though that one folder which content I really need is suddenly empty (0b in properties) with all files gone.
I am sure I didn't delete anything.
Since a different folder now contains files I didn't put there, which can't be deleted (Dolphin error, can't be deleted) I am sure there is something wrong with the system and not with me deleting anything.
These are my system specs.
   Operating System: Kubuntu 24.04
   KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.11
   KDE Frameworks Version: 5.115.0
   Qt Version: 5.15.13
   Kernel Version: 6.8.0-49-generic (64-bit)
   Graphics Platform: X11
   Processors: 12 × Intel Core i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz
   Memory: 7,6 GiB of RAM
   Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 630
   Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
   Product Name: Inspiron 3670
I searched online, where for diagnostics everybody recommended the use of a 'disks' app, which I can't find on my system.
Instead I did use sudo badblocks -s -v -n -f /dev/sda2, but no errors were found and sudo fsck -cfvr /dev/sda2 didn't do anything.
The file system of the drive is ntfs it is mounted under /mnt/media/jascha/ and has still 79% free space.
I used the KDE partition manager to unmount and remount, but that didn't help, either.
I am not sure what to do or how to get back my files and I am a bit afraid right now to do any work because I don't know if I might lose that as well.

Are you sure you've disabled fastboot and aren't hibernating windows. Windows fastboot and hibernate cause windows to cache details of the file-system as it allows faster boot/resuming, HOWEVER it also will not detect any changes made if another OS is booted (ie. dual boot) which the windows documentation warned about (when first introduced) meaning lost files and/or potential for corruption where NTFS is used. As Microsoft warned, do NOT fastboot or hibernate windows where dual booting is used (and shared NTFS)

Hi.
Thanks for your answer.
There is no longer any Windows on the machine, the drive was completely wiped and Ubuntu is the only OS used.
